# Asking manager for full time position

Tags: new-job, job-change

I'm a student and working part-time in a company as a developer. The company policy is that when someone graduates then they might ask them to join as a full time employee. Recently, the majority of the students have been asked, but my problem is that I don't speak German very well so I'm not sure about my chances. I am working here for 1 year and will graduate in about 3 months. As I am non-European and have visa conditions, I can't wait for their answer until graduation.

I wanted to know what is appropriate way to ask my manager for full time employment.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange a 1-1 meeting with him and put together a "business" case for yourself - prep some details about your accomplishments while you have been working there and what you would hope to bring to the company in the future if you were hired. If you have any areas where you know you need to improve (such as the German language skills you mention in your post) then try and put together some planned actions you can take to improve upon them.

The idea is that rather than going in and having a conversation that is basically "give me a job" it's "employ me and it will benefit the company in x,y and z ways"

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is that I don't speak german very well so I'm not sure about my chances.

Giving that you are considering a very short term and that it will be almost impossible to improve significantly your German skills in that time, whatever your chances are will not change. You will know those when you ask him for the full time position<sup>1</sup>.

> As I am non European and have visa conditions so I can't wait for there answer until graduation.

That is a very valid concern that justifies asking a meeting with him, explaining that situation and seeing if he can give you an earlier answer.

That would be a good opportunity to ask him if s/he considers your German skills lacking, and if he thinks that you should be taking some German classes (on your own time) after you have graduated, if you continue working there. That would show him your good disposition towards making things go smoothly.

---

<sup>1</sup>As someone said, worry about the things you can change, not about the things you cannot.